# How to create Globals Array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, global

How do you create an array in GLOBALS for php?

for example, I want to do something like this:

```
$GLOBALS["chapter_names"] = array();
```

and then

```
$GLOBALS["chapter_names"][$i] = $row -> CHAPTER_NAME;
```

inside a while loop

where `$i` is the index of the array

is this the optimal way to do things?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried? If not, why not? If yes, what happens? If you have a problem then it is not apparent which problem. You have to explain better.

Comment: Using globals is best prevented, as it will make maintaining, testing en debugging your code harder. However, your exact example would work.

Comment: It worked, but I just wanted to know if I was using the right code. I know very very little php. Thank you!

Comment: that's quite odd reason to ask questions. Usually people tend to ask if something is NOT working. And if you're asking for the better solution, you have to describe your goal. While you aren't

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: sounds like they just want to confirm that they aren't shooting themselves in the foot. Don't think there's anything wrong with looking for best practices

Comment: He's learning php and he doesn't know if the working code has some negative consequences he still doesn't know about and learn if there a "better practice". I don't see anything wrong about that.

Answer (score 6):

```
$GLOBALS["chapter_names"] = array();
foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    array_push($GLOBALS["chapter_names"], $row->CHAPTER_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much exactly as you gave it there. Except you don't need to put an index of $i  when you're adding new stuff, unless it needs some specific index. You could just do it something like this:

```
$GLOBALS['chapter_names'] = array();
$GLOBALS['chapter_names'][] = $row -> CHAPTER_NAME;


print_r($GLOBALS);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
$GLOBALS["chapter_names"] = array();

$row = new StdClass;

$row->CHAPTER_NAME = 'test';

$i = 0;

$GLOBALS["chapter_names"][$i] = $row -> CHAPTER_NAME;

var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

Amongst other things, the value is displayed...

```
["chapter_names"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "test"
```

However, as you are probably aware, variables should only have as much scope as required, to prevent clashes and possible problems. Therefore, global variables should be avoided in most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $GLOBALS, it's an outdated and quite dangerous practice. You can read about the Registry pattern - it's an OO solution to the problem. As for your example, it should be completely working.

Comment: Pff, a `Registry` is about as evil a global, it shares many of the flaws used in arguments against globals. If you want to provide maintainable OO solutions, one would be better off talking about dependency injection et al.

Comment: Thanx, chap! Though Registry is used in most modern mainstream frameworks, like ZF, if it tells you something. BTW, Registry is not so unsecure as $GLOBALS (RTFM please). And it's as easy to use as $GLOBALS. Yes, it is not an ideal solution, but is there any?

Comment: Well, the fact the 'most modern mainstream frameworks' use it is in my personal opinion a sign OO in PHP still hasn't matured yet. True, a Registry can have it's place, but it suffers from almost all drawbacks of the `$GLOBALS` we know, which if often overlooked by people simply substituting globals for registries (which are in most cases, just 'fancy globals'). I think [this guy summarized it nicely](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2007/10/26/registry-pattern-or-dependency-injection-container/).

Comment: Thank you for a useful link. AFAIK, dependency injection has its own drawbacks. I didn't mean to offend anybody. That was just IMHO, as I have some experience developing PHP. BTW, you wrote above "Using globals is best prevented, as it will make maintaining, testing en debugging your code harder" - I completely agree to it. Again, the author of the question said "I know very very little php". And I think, Registry is much easier for novice than dependency injection

Comment: You've got a point there. Dependency injection, while not necessarily more work, does require more thinking ahead then a Registry and maybe a bit more experience.